# Passing queue to process ran in executor

Tags: python-3.x, queue, python-multiprocessing, executor

I am unable to pass `multiprocessing.Queue` as an argument to a function ran in `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```
def my_task(q):
    while condition:
        network_task()
        q.put(current_state)

queue = Queue()
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
loop.run_in_executor(executor, my_task, queue)
queue.get()
```

This raises `RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`. I'd like `my_task` of indeterminate runtime to deliver updates on its state while running, so that main loop can act accordingly, scheduling additional `my_task` instances where and when required. Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible, and if so how?